# Is there any possibility to copy the data from crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports-xi

I Am Using crystal report 9.
Is there any possibility to copy the data from crystal report viewer?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to copy the data from a report in Crystal Reports. I'm not 100% for crystal report 9 however I except it to be the same as in XI:

-Navigate to File (top left of the window) -> Export -> Export Report. At this point there are several options to export the data (pdf, excel, etc.)